# time complexity of HashSet

Tags: time-complexity

I was discussing with a friend about the Hashset design using mod function as the Hashing function.
The time complexity of such implementation appears to be O(N/K) , where N is total items stored in the set and k is total # of buckets. This time complexity assumes that that all items are distributed among all buckets and bucket's average size is N/K.

I confused myself because i believe the time complexity should be O(N). Since time complexity is the worst case performance. Here the worst case could be that all N items go to same bucket and value we are looking for could be at the end of the bucket. Please help me here.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that the worst case is all items going into one bucket. The items being evenly distributed is the best case. That said, O(N/k) is the same as O(N) if k is held constant, since constants can be neglected. I would not expect k to be part of the input to a lookup anyway. If k can vary, then it is different, but the worst case is still O(N).